# Dynamically adding new files to existing python process

Tags: python, django

We use Django for a project. Prior to 1.7+, we were able to dynamically pull in files to our python environment when setup.py was being executed. For example, we have this directory structure:

```
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/__init__.py
/foo/bar/my_functions.py
```

Our Django project doesn't know anything about those files to start off. When the web server starts and setup.py is read, we look at a configuration which tells us where to find files to add to our environment. Again, let's assume `/foo/bar` is in our configuration to be dynamically loaded. We would then use `import_module()` to import it so that anything under `/foo/bar` essentially becomes part of the project and can be used. It's basically a "plugins" feature.

After Django >=1.7, this causes huge problems, mainly:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure
cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you
don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.
```

It also limits our ability to add new files dynamically as you always have to put them in place and restart your web server. You couldn't have an "Upload Plugin" page to add new files to the server, for example.

Is there a way to add files like this both during the web server startup as well as after the startup without restarting it?

Comment: have you followed the suggestion described in the error msg? See the docs for the [lazy versions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation)

Comment: Yes I've looked at the fixes for that traceback and we already had that code in place. If I remove any reference to dynamically loading content the error goes away but obviously not what we want for a situation.